# Most pythonic (and efficient) way of nesting a list in pairs

Tags: python, list, python-itertools, list-comprehension

my list is:

```
mylist=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

I would like to convert mylist into a list of pairs:

```
[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
```

Is there a pythonic way of doing so? List comprehension? Itertools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[mylist[2*n:2*n+2] for n in xrange(len(mylist)/2)]`

This solution combines the use of list comprehensions and slicing to extract pairs in sequence from the original list, and build a list of the slices.

Alternatively, `[mylist[n:n+2] for n in xrange(0, len(mylist), 2)]` which is the same except `xrange` counts by twos instead of the slices.  Thanks to Steven Rumbalski for the suggestion.

And now for something completely different: here is a solution (ab)using `zip` and an ephemeral function instead of intermediate assignment:

```
>>> (lambda i: zip(i, i))(iter(mylist))
[(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]
```

Comment: More complicated than it needs to be -- just step `xrange` by 2 and most of the math goes away.

Answer (score 9):

Yeppers, list comprehension is my usual way of doing it:

```
>>> groupsize = 2
>>> [mylist[x:x+groupsize] for x in range(0,len(mylist),groupsize)]
[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
>>> groupsize = 3
>>> [mylist[x:x+groupsize] for x in range(0,len(mylist),groupsize)]
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
```

I use `range` for portability, if you are using python 2 (you probably are) change the `range` to `xrange` to save memory.

Answer (score 8):

My preferred technique:

```
>>> mylist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> mylist = iter(mylist)
>>> zip(mylist, mylist)
[(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]
```

I usually use generators instead of lists anyway, so line 2 usually isn't required.

Comment: For added fun, change the zip to `zip(*[mylist]*groupsize)` to allow for generic group size. Of course, the zip way is always going to have a problem with handling lists that have a length that is not divisible by the desired group size.

Comment: This seems like the "most pythonic" way to do this.

Comment: @BrianM.Hunt I don't know that I would agree with that. The zen of python says "Simple is better than complex", and if you don't understand exactly how zip and iterators work, that could hardly be called simple. It's certainly the most clever way, though.

Comment: @Josiah I kind of agree with you, although If one can zip two different generators together, one knows they can zip a generator with itself sequentially. I have found this technique to be fairly safe. especially if you were to go for (x, y) in zip(points, points), for example it can be obvious

Answer (score 6):

An alternate way:

```
zip( mylist[:-1:2], mylist[1::2] )
```

Which produces a list of tuples:

```
>>> zip(mylist[:-1:2],mylist[1::2])
[(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]
```

If you really want a list of lists:

```
map(list, zip(mylist[:-1:2],mylist[1::2]))
```

Answer (score 5):

Check out the "grouper" recipe from the [itertools documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html):

```
def grouper(n, iterable, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper(3, 'ABCDEFG', 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)
```

Comment: -1.  This will give 5 pairs on a 6 item sequence, which is incorrect.  If you want an itertools recipe, it should be `grouper`.